# What does the Alt-Shift-Esc keyboard shortcut do?

Tags: shortcut-keys, gnome-shell

Accidentally I found this keyboard shortcut, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>. It iterates over all open windows in current workspace with some Orange border.
I searched on the internet but found nothing about it.

So just wanted to know, what actually this shortcut is?
I am currently on Xorg Gnome ubuntu 17.10.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the GNOME Shell documentation](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/keyboard-nav.html.en):

> <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>
>
> Cycle through all open windows on a workspace.

Adding <kbd>Shift</kbd> to a cycling shortcut usually just reverses the order (compare <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>).

Comment: In my case (16.04, gnome) adding shift does not simply reverse the action. Instead, with alt-esc I can only change between the last two windows, only with shift I can cycle through all open windows.

Comment: @SebastianStark since the behaviour you describe for Alt Esc is clearly different from the docs, either you're seeing a bug or the behaviour changed after whichever version of GNOME 16.04 uses

Comment: @muru I don't think your second hypothesis (i.e. "behaviour changed after whichever version of GNOME 16.04") is true, alt+esc does cycle through *all* open windows on a workspace here (Ubuntu 17.10, GNOME v3.26). So it seems either it's a bug or Sebastian somehow overrode the default behaviour.

Comment: Correct, something is different with my 16.04 installation (not sure what, I didn't override it), on another machine running 18.04 beta alt-esc behaves as described.